# Connecting html pages + Razor to database

Tags: c#, database, asp.net, razor

I am doing a **learning** project in which i wanted to combine Html+Razor and connect it to Database.

**Steps I followed**.

1. Created a sample form ( which i intend to use to execute "insert" and "update" queries )
2. Created Database (Name: TestDatabase.mdf, located inside App_Data)
3. Put in some sample values in the database with Table name "Student"
   [image: Student Table]
4. updated the webconfig file as follows (ConnectionString was obtained by copying it from Database explorer)

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="TestDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TestDatabase.mdf;Integrated   Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
   </connectionStrings>
   ```
5. Inserted the Razor code for connection as follows

   ```
   @{
      var db = Database.Open("TestDatabase");
      var query = "Select * Student";
   }

   <html>
       <head>
           <title>Testing For Database Connectivity</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <div>
               <fieldset>
                   <legend>Some Sample Form</legend>
                   <form>
                       <div>
                           <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label>
                           <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
                       </div>
                       <div>
                           <label for="LastName">LastName</label>
                           <input type="text" name="LastName" />
                       </div>
                       <div>
                           <label for="SSN">SSN</label>
                           <input type="text" name="SSN" />
                       </div>
                       <div>
                           <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                       </div>
                       <div>
                           @foreach (var row in db.Query(query))
                           {                    
                               @row.FirstName
                               <br />
                           }
                       </div>
                   </form>
               </fieldset>
           </div>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

But i am getting the following error

**Stacktrace**

```
[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'attachdbfilename'.]
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword) +192
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object         value) +31
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value) +185
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString) +177
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +239
WebMatrix.Data.DbProviderFactoryWrapper.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +96
WebMatrix.Data.<>c__DisplayClass15.<OpenConnectionStringInternal>b__14() +16
WebMatrix.Data.Database.get_Connection() +19
WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen() +12
WebMatrix.Data.<QueryInternal>d__0.MoveNext() +71
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +327
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
WebMatrix.Data.Database.Query(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +103
ASP._Page_TestPage_cshtml.Execute() in d:\ASP.NET\RefreshTesting\TestPage.cshtml:33
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +209
System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +68
System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +152
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext,   TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase  httpContext) +121
```

**Error Page Image**

[image: Error displayed]

I am trying to be very clear and informative but if i have missed out to mention something then please let me know.
I don't know now where i am going wrong or i am making a silly mistake and now i am even doubting that whether this is possible or not. I am new to microsoft languages and i have watched a couple of Youtube videos which use some MVC thing to achieve it. is it possible to do it the way i have done ?? If yes please help me and if NO then what could be my possible options?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you correctly created a SQL Server CE database?

I believe that should be an .sdf file, not an .mdf file.

What happens if you change the providerName part of your connection string from `"System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"` to `"System.Data.SqlClient"`?

Comment: okay i tried the methods you suggested but still unsuccessful  <br/> Steps as to how i created Database initially  <br/> 1. Right Click on App_Data --> Add New Item --> Sql Server Database   <br/> 2. Opened its properties and Copied Connection String  <br/><br/> i made the following changes and tried but still its giving error <br/><br/> i even created **.sdf** Database and updated the connection string but still its giving error

Comment: What error did you get when you changed the provider name in the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

As you created Sql Server Database, then you should set **providerName** as **System.Data.SqlClient**.

And I don't see your `Initial Catalog` setting, I mean you have to set which database you would connect to.

Could you please try to add connection string like this?

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="TestDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\TestDatabase.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

where `DBName` is database name which you want to connect.